# Is the cordova app a Web app or Hybrid app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

Please this is not about a literal listing of differences . This requires a practical understanding of the mobile development.
[image]
As seen in the above definition, there is a clear difference between mobile web app and mobile website.
Now, I have created a phonegap project named **Hello** (html,css, js) then use this **phonegap run android** command to export it to my android phone.
Is this app running on my android a **web app or an hybrid app** ?
Beyond cordova , I need to clear this doubt about the Web app and hybrid.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it in't a programming problem but a terminology / concept question

Comment: @XGouchet  I think you have not understood my question.

Comment: From what I understood, you're asking if an app created with phonegap / cordova is seen as an Hybrid app or Web app. This is not a technical problem, but just terminology : what label you can set on the application you built. Thus it doesn't belong in the stack overflow website (but could be asked on other stack exchange site). Besides the definition of Hybrid / web app is highly opinion based, and so there's no objective answer to your question

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, I get something important from your answer. "<<definition of Hybrid / web app is highly opinion based>>" That is what lead me to the confusion...Regards

Answer (score 2):

> As seen in the above definition, there is a clear difference between mobile web app and mobile website.

The authors of wherever you got that grid are welcome to their opinion as to what the differences are "between mobile web app and mobile website". My opinion is that those authors are inexperienced, as everything in the "Pure mobile web apps" column would apply equally well to "Pure mobile web sites".

> Is this app running on my android a web app or an hybrid app ?

It is a hybrid app. More directly, it is not a "Pure mobile web app" as defined by that grid, as it is not "written entirely in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript". There is Java code incorporated in your app, along with other items related to Android (e.g., resources defined in XML). The fact that you get that Java code and other stuff from a third party (Apache Cordova) does not mean that it somehow does not exist.

Comment: Very good answer, but is it possible to write a pure web app (html, js, css) and deploy or install it locally on an android phone ? Launched from a shortcut icon. The problem I am having is the way or which tool to use develop this type of web apps (not remote mobile website). I hope you get what I mean..

Comment: @soulemanemoumie: That depends on what you mean by "deploy or install". HTML5 supports offline caching, through the cache manifest. People who bookmark an HTML5 Web app -- one that is properly written -- can use that app offline, at least as much as the app allows (e.g., only has access to local storage, until the device goes online again). However, if you are looking to distribute through the Play Store, then you need an APK, and the only way to get an APK using HTML/CSS/JS is through some variation of a hybrid app framework (Cordova or others).

Comment: I may agree with you that those authors maybe be inexperienced. Because  I was also seeing those two possibilities you mentioned either developing a mobile web app (html, css, js) and convert it using tools like cordova to make it hybrid and install in the phone. Or  Caching a normal mobile website. But installing a pure (html, css, js) web app for example on android without making it hybrid I don't see how is it possible. at least someone come up with something..Thanks once more